# WPF Выбор элемента для отображения

Tags: wpf, xml

Мне нужен редактируемый список на WPF, который будет сохранять, и редактировать XML, какой элемент мне выбрать? DATAGRID? Требования к дизайну прокрутка, цветовая схема для четных и нечетных записей, в случае отсутствия данных другой пустой шаблон, помогите определится, также прошу подсказать ссылки на мануал загрузки и редактирование xml.

Comment: какой элемент выбрать дело вкуса. Исходя из описания, мне кажется, что будет удобно выбрать `ListBox`.

Comment: Вы спрашиваете не о том. Вопрос в том, что вы хотите показать _семантически_. Какой смысл вашего XML-объекта? Дом? Сотрудник предприятия? Купленный товар?

Comment: Контрола для показа бессеммантичного XML нету потому, что для разной семантики нужно разное представление.

Comment: а требования к дизайну - `wpf` достаточно гибкий, чтобы реализовать все перечисленное без всяких проблем

Comment: я дополню ответ как только у меня будет время =)

Answer (score 0):

Какой элемент вам выбрать зависит от того, что вы хотите получить в итоге. `WPF` позволяет легко настраивать внешний вид, так что ответ на такой вопрос будет - любой. В том числе и предложенный `DataGrid`.

Чтобы ответ был более понятный, давайте рассмотрим несколько примеров как вы можете отобразить ваши данные с различными элементами управления. Естественно, список будет далеко не полный, но вы сможете от этого отталкиваться. Набор данных я взял из вашего предыдущего вопроса (хотя есть проблемы с кодировкой)

1.
**ListView**

Если вам нужно отображать свойства ваше объекта в виде таблицы, но без возможности редактировать прямо в ней, то хорошим выбором, на мой взгляд, будет этот элемент управления.

Пример разметки:

```
<ListView AlternationCount="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <AlternationConverter x:Key="altconvBackground">
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Orange" />
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="LightGray" />
                </AlternationConverter>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="30"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}"
                                    Header="ID" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="200"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"
                                    Header="Имя" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="200"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Last}"
                                    Header="Фамилия" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="50"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}"
                                    Header="Возраст" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="50"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Gender}"
                                    Header="Пол" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="Удалить">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        Content="X"
                                        Padding="3" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), Converter={StaticResource altconvBackground}}" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

Обратите внимание на свойство `AlternationCount`, которое показывает какое количество стилей вы хотите использовать.

Отображение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конечно, `true`/`false` выглядят совсем не хорошо, но вы легко можете настроить отображение с помощью конвертера. А мне не хотелось раздувать ответ большим количеством деталей.

Учитывая, что вам нужно редактировать данные, то удобно будет вынести этот функционал непосредственно под нашу таблицу.